# Android Studio showing this error

Tags: android, android-studio

> Gradle 'MyApplication' project refresh failed
>   Error:C:\Users\Hirtul.gradle\daemon\2.4\registry.bin.lock (Access is denied)

Comment: do you use an online cloud provider like dropbox, gdrive or anything like that? sometimes it syncs relevant classes in the background and android studio wants to rewrite them while building.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you don't have permissions over `C:\Users\Hirtul.gradle\daemon\2.4\registry.bin.lock`.

Just open Android Studio in Admin Mode (or sudo, superuser, whatever you want to call it) or change the permissions of `C:\Users\Hirtul.gradle\daemon\2.4\registry.bin.lock` to rwx (777)